# A multiple integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, integration

Let us consider the multiple integral
$$I_{n}=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }ds_{1}\int_{-\infty}^{s_{1}}ds_{2}\cdots 
\int_{-\infty }^{s_{2n-1}}ds_{2n}\;\cos {(s_{1}^{2}-s_{2}^{2})}\;\cdots 
\cos {(s_{2n-1}^{2}-s_{2n}^{2})}.$$

Using an indirect method (Landau-Zener formula from the theory of molecular scattering), we had shown in http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1975 that
$$I_n=\frac{2}{n!}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{\,n}.$$
I'm very interested how to get this result by direct mathematical (preferably simple) methods, without using the Landau-Zener formula. Can anyone help?

Actually, I asked similar question an year ago [Multiple Integral (American Mathematical Monthly problem 11621 and its generalization)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125237/multiple-integral-american-mathematical-monthly-problem-11621-and-its-generali) but have not got an answer.